# Failed to build byobu from source (no root permissions)

Tags: permissions, gnome-terminal, make, byobu, restricted-access

I don't have root access. Have tried with `autoreconf -ivf` but nothing works

#### Steps I am trying to follow:

```bsh
wget https://launchpad.net/byobu/trunk/5.17/+download/byobu_5.17.orig.tar.gz
tar -zxvf byobu_5.17.orig.tar.gz
rm byobu_5.17.orig.tar.gz
cd byobu*
./configure --prefix="$HOME/byobu"
make
make install
```

#### Output from make:

```
chowdhury@exs-91208:~/byobu-5.17$ make
Making all in etc/byobu
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
Making all in etc/profile.d
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/profile.d'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/profile.d'
Making all in usr/share/applications
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/usr/share/applications'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.aking all in usr/share/man/man1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/usr/share/man/man1'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/usr/share/man/man1'
Making all in usr/bin
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/usr/bin'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/usr/bin'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17'
```

#### Output from make install:

```
chy@exs-91208:~/byobu-5.17$ make install
Making install in etc/byobu
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/etc/byobu/'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/etc’: Permission denied
Makefile:248: recipe for target 'install-etcDATA' failed
make[2]: *** [install-etcDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
Makefile:318: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
Makefile:325: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: The output of `make` would likely be more informative than that of `make clean`

Comment: `byobu` :  Ubuntu 16.04 ... 19.04 → `sudo apt install byobu` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=byobu&searchon=names

Comment: @steeldriver, make doesn't work too.

Comment: @KnudLarsen, i don't have root permission so sudo is not an option

Comment: @steeldriver, sure. i have posted the output for "make"

Comment: "Nothing to be done for 'all'." : Means that everything is OK.

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks for the help. he error i'm getting for the next step, i.e, "make install"----is posted

Comment: @steeldriver, no the problem is with root access. It works on my local machine.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `./configure --prefix="$HOME/byobu"` hasn't taken effect, and it is trying to use `--prefix=/usr` - I don't know why, I just tested it on my machine and it happily installed into `"$HOME/byobu"` for me. What does `grep prefix config.log` say?

Comment: @Nmath no - the OP has already stated that they don't have sudo access, and they are clearly trying to install into `$HOME`

Answer (score 4):

Byobu can be build and installed without any root privileges. It does not need binary or artifact installation outside the `--prefix=` directory.

Following the steps you described, there is something wrong with the `$HOME` variable. After extracting and configuring Byobo:

```
$ tar xf byobu_5.17.orig.tar.gz && cd byobu-5.17 && ./configure --prefix="$HOME/byobu"
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes

...

config.status: creating usr/share/man/man1/Makefile
config.status: creating usr/bin/Makefile
```

The `config.log` should contain the prefix:

```
$ grep ^prefix config.log 
prefix='/home/chy/byobu'
```

I presume, in your case it looks more like this:

```
$ grep ^prefix config.log 
prefix='/usr'
```

With that `--prefix` I am able to reproduce your error:

```
$ make install
Making install in etc/byobu
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/etc/byobu/" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/etc/byobu/"
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/etc': Permission denied
Makefile:185: recipe for target 'install-etcDATA' failed
make[2]: *** [install-etcDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
Makefile:252: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chy/byobu-5.17/etc/byobu'
Makefile:238: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Reset the source directory and restart the configuration and use an absolute path for the prefix:

```
$ cd byobu-5.17/
$ make distclean
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/chy/byobu
$ make && make install
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/chy/byobu/bin

$ byobu
```

Byobu will however only work, if the [tmux](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tmux) packet is installed.